# how to import sax parser into angular2 using typescript

Tags: json, typescript, angular, sax

Trying to include the sax parser and running into difficulties [parser.ts].

```
import sax = require("sax");
export class MyParser {
   //my parser code 
}
```

When I try to use it [app.component.ts]:

```
import {MyParser} from './parser'
...
constructor(private http: Http, private parser: MyParser) {}
```

I get this error

```
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/sax
```

Which I know means SystemJS cannot find the module.  Sax is installed in node_modules and listed in package.json.  I've installed typings using

```
typings install --ambient sax
```

But getting lots of duplicate identifier warnings even though my tsconfig.json is excluding

```
"exclude": [
  "node_modules",
  "typings/main",
  "typings/main.d.ts"
]
```

Lastly, isaacs uses code like this in his examples

```
 tag.parent
 tag.children
```

This isn't supported by the typing (d.ts).

Does anyone have a working install of sax with TS and ng2?

Comment: The code seems fine, maybe there's an error with the way you configured SystemJS?

Answer (score 1):

The error you have is at runtime. So I think that you could try to configure SystemJS this way:

```
<script>
  System.config({
    paths: {
      sax: './node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js'
    }
  })
</script>
```

This way you will be able to import Sax:

```
import {SAXParser} from 'sax';
```