# Angular2, SaxParser, sax.js, unexpected token `<`

Tags: angular, sax

I'm using the SaxParser (sax.js) in angular2 (typescript).

The setup is like [Stackoverflow: how to import sax parser into angular2 using typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35971560/how-to-import-sax-parser-into-angular2-using-typescript) :

systemjs.config.js:

```js
...
var map = {
  ...
  'sax':    'node_modules/sax'
};
var packages = {
  ...
  'sax':    { defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
...
var config = {
  map: map,
  ...
}
System.config(config);
...
```

In my `index.html` I've included

```html
<script src="node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js"></script>
```

Now I've created saxParser.ts:

```js
import { SAXParser } from 'sax';

export class SaxParser {
  parser;
  options = {
    lowercase: true,
    normalize: true,
    xmlns: true,
    position: true,
  }

  constructor() {
    this.parser = new SAXParser(true, this.options);
  }
}
```

Using it in my Service like:

```
someFunction() {
  ...
  let parser = new SaxParser();
  ...
}
```

Now I got the following error:

> Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>           at Object.eval (http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/saxParser/saxParser.js:2:13)
>           at eval (http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/saxParser/saxParser.js:17:4)
>           at eval (http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/saxParser/saxParser.js:18:3)
>       Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:37420/node_modules/sax
>       Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/saxParser/saxParser.js
>       Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/services/parseXml.service.js
>       Evaluating http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/services/parseXml.service.spec.js
>       Error loading http://127.0.0.1:37420/app/services/parseXml.service.spec.jsZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:323Zone.run @ zone.js:216(anonymous function) @ zone.js:571ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:474ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426

The codeline throwing this error is:

```js
var sax_1 = require('sax');
```

I'm not sure if it's an import problem or something other (because of the unexpected `<` ).. . Does anyone know this error? And how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: ///<reference path="../node_modules/sax/lib/sax..d.ts"/> add this in boot .ts and try

Comment: @mayur what?

Where are you hosting/developing this? On linux/mac?

Comment: There isn't a `*.d.ts`, only a `sax.js` which seems to have everything needed. I've got the same error with  `///<reference path="../node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js"/>` in my `main.ts`.

Comment: Adding a reference hint for the TypeScript compiler surely wouldn't help in executing the JS in your browser. The fact you're getting a '<' on requiring the JS file seems to point to a HTTP error. So maybe you don't have permission to load it or it's just not at that path.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify your `systemjs.config.js` file like this:

```js
var map = {
  ...
  'sax':    'node_modules/sax/lib'
};
var packages = {
  ...
  'sax':    { main: 'sax.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

Comment: Now I got the following errors: > GET http://127.0.0.1:46779/stream 404 (Not Found) > Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://127.0.0.1:46779/stream > GET http://127.0.0.1:46779/string_decoder 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It seems there are several more packages missing, sax is depending on. `stream`, `string_decoder`, `buffer`, `emitter`. Just install those and set the map/packages the same way like you did with sax.

Comment: If I add `'sax': { defaultExtension: 'js' },   'buffer': { defaultExtension: 'js' }, ...` then I'll get the same error. If I add `main: 'sax.js'` then I've got the unexpected token `<` in `string_decoder`. If I  add `main: index.js` to `'string_decoder': { defaultExtension: 'js' },` I got an error depending `buffer` (and so on). If I add to `stream`, `string_decoder`, `buffer` and `emiter` the `main: index.js` I get 404's on: `asynclist`, `util`, `ieee754`, base64-js` and `isarray`...

Comment: Yes, i experienced the same issue and didn't dive deeper, since I'm not exactly an expert with SystemJS. :(

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying. (y) I've done in `stream`, `string_decoder`, `buffer` and `emitter`, `npm install -g` but it does not help..